# Get the last inserted data from mysql table , filtering by categories

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database which has 4 columns

```
ID
CATEGORY
NAME
DATA
```

How could I retrieve the last inserted value of `DATA` which is filtered by `CATEGORY`

Comment: Is the id auto increment?  Do you want to get his right after the insert or later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear whether you want the last value for a given category, or by category, so here's both solutions:

For a given category:

```
select data from mytable
where category = ?
order by id desc
limit 1;
```

For all categories:

```
select category, data
from (select * from mytable 
    order by id desc) x
group by category;
```

Note that the second query is a mysql-only solution, but since this is a mysql question, this will work.

Comment: The first one won't work in oracle either, but this s a MySQL question

Comment: @PeterWooster Well, the syntax for limiting the rows might be different, but the principle will work. The second query will explode in all databases I know of except mysql.

Comment: True, but applying a limit in Oracle using Rownum isn't obvious except to those who have already been there.

Comment: @Bohemian +1 BTW I noticed you made it top to the Winter Bash =) Congratulations.

Comment: @bonCodigo thanks! As far as I can tell I got every hat except one: the bushido (same as necromancer). I got close though... Only needed two more votes on an answer. Oh well, nm

Comment: @Bohemian Blimey!.. would have just sent a buzz around this way ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select * from your_table where ID = Max(ID)
```

Comment: This isn't answering the question at all; there's no mention of category in this query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that id is an auto incremented id you need something like:

```
Select data from mytable
Where category = :mycategory
Order by id desc
Limit 1
```